# Most important variable in a principal component

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

How do I tell what is the most important variable for a particular principal component? Do I calculate the absolute value for all the eigenvectors associated with that particular principal component and choose the largest one?

Comment: This should be reflected by the factor (or component) loadings

Answer (score 0):

although your question does not provide any details about the methodology but based on my own learning and study, what you want to do is interpretation of PCA/EOF output. That is usually consist of three parts, Variance, Eigenvectors and Principal component (PC). Now what does this PCA/EOF do is only shows the pattern in a bulk of data. The importance depends on many things but usually variance is the prime one and should be noted. Principal component provide the deviation/temporal evolution over time showing certain degree of deviation while eigenvalue is spatial evolution over a grid or pixel scale or individual data. the PC sign(either +/-) is used along with variance of each mode (eigenvectors of pixel or individual data) to quantify the temporal evolution of the data in both space and time. I hope this is what you wanted to know, otherwise  please refer to [a cautionary note on the interpretation of EOF](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0442%282002%29015%3C0216%3AACNOTI%3E2.0.CO%3B2).

Answer (score 0):

calculate the absolute value (magnitude) for all the weightings in the eigenvector for that PC, the largest is the biggest contributor,with contribution declining by magnitude.

The score is the $PC * Data$ so the larger the weighting, the bigger influence on the score value. Note for math people, PCs are unit vectors so linear algebra multiplication and transpose of the inverse give the same result.

Ideally you want each PC to carry large weights from numerous variables, otherwise its not really a linear combination. The single largest contributor is rarely useful, rather the dominant pattern is important.